# Google Earth "ERR_CREATE_PLUGIN"

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-earth-plugin

I've come across a weird error.  I'm trying to load the Google Earth libraries but when doing so am getting the error "ERR_CREATE_PLUGIN"

The following code DOES work:

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script>
    google.load("earth", "1");

    var ge = null;

    function init() {
        google.earth.createInstance("map3d", initCallback, failureCallback);
    }

    function initCallback(object) {
        ge = object;
        ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true);
    }

    function failureCallback(object) {
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload='init()' id='body'>
    <center>
        <div id='map3d'
            style='border: 1px solid silver; height: 600px; width: 800px;'></div>
    </center>
</body>
```

While this code does not:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("earth", "1");

    var ge = null;

    function initCallback(object) {
        ge = object;
        ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true);
    }

    function failureCallback(object) {
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {


        google.earth.createInstance("map3d", initCallback, failureCallback);    
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that won't work is because jquery may load before the Google Earth API.

That is `google.earth.createInstance()` is getting called by `jquery` in `$(document).ready()` before `google.load()` has finished.

To ensure everything is loaded correctly before calling `createInstance()` - simply load both, jquery and the earth api, from the [Google loader](https://developers.google.com/loader/) via the `google.load()` method. That way you can then use the `setOnLoadCallback` method to know when everything is ready. i.e.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  google.load("jquery", "1"); 
  google.load("earth", "1"); 
  google.setOnLoadCallback(function() { 
    //Place init code here instead of $(document).ready()
    google.earth.createInstance("map3d", initCallback, failureCallback);   
  }); 

  // etc...
```