# Fix Google Earth “ERR_CREATE_PLUGIN” Closed Network

Tags: javascript, enterprise, google-earth-plugin, google-loader

I have a problem very similar to [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19987747/google-earth-err-create-plugin) but the only problem is that I'm on a closed network and and I'm using the enterprise library [earth_plugin_loader.js](https://support.google.com/earthenterprise/answer/6051568?hl=en)

```
<script type="[MyServer]/earth_api/earth_plugin_loader.js">
<script type="text/javascript">
//google.load("earth", "1"); < Don't have that or the google loader API

var ge = null;

function initCallback(object) {
    ge = object;
    ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true);
}

function failureCallback(object) {
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    google.earth.createInstance("map3d", initCallback, failureCallback);    
});
```

To load the api I simply add the script to my header, is there anyway for me to know when the api is done loading?

Comment: Use the `load` event instead of `$(document).ready`.

Comment: if you are referring to google.loader I don't have it since it's the enterprise edition

Comment: `google.setOnLoadCallback` is the same as `$(window).load`.